# stop Observable.interval and send onComplete

Tags: android, rx-java

I have the following scenario in mind: I would like to have a timer counts up till I unsubscribe but I want to get the onComplete signal once I stop with last value.

```
observable = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnNext(new Action1<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Long aLong) {
                    String duration = Utils.getDuration(startedTrackingTime, new Date().getTime());
                    view.updateDurationTextView(duration);
                }
            });

    subscription = observable.subscribe();



public void stopMission() {
        observable.doOnCompleted(new Action0() {
            @Override
            public void call() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCompleted: " + "timer");
            }
        });

        subscription.unsubscribe();
```

The doOnComplete never called. Is it possible to do it with RxJava? I feel I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@MatBos is correct that if you unsubscribe you cannot expect a completion emission. However, if you want to stop the observable early and get it to complete you can merge the interval with a `PublishSubject` and send a stop message through the subject whenever you want to:

```
PublishSubject<Long> subject = PublishSubject.create();
subject
    .mergeWith(Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) 
    .takeWhile(n -> n != -1) 
    .doOnNext(System.out::println) 
    .doOnCompleted(() -> System.out.println("completed"))
    .subscribe();
Thread.sleep(3100);
subject.onNext(-1L);
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Gives:

```
0
1
2
completed
```

Answer (score 2):

Interval observable is infinite thus never completes. I would suggest to use `doOnUnsubscribe` for your stop callback instead of `doOnCompleted`.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of the [onComplete](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html):

> An Observable calls this method **after it has called onNext for the final time**, if it has not encountered any errors.

When you call unsubscribe you only stop receiving emissions.
So the observable may continue to emit items via onNext or stop emissions with onComplete/onError notification but you just said you are not interested with what it emits so you do not receive it.